# Was salvation available to Lucifer and those angels who rebelled with him?

Tags: sin, satan, assurance-of-salvation

Revelation describes the nature of the event that led to Lucifer's demise. It seems to be quite clear that Lucifer and his angels, in rebelling against God, engaged in an act of terrible sin.

> <sup>**7**</sup> And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,
> <sup>**8**</sup> And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven.
> <sup>**9**</sup> And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.
> <sup>**10**</sup> And I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, Now is come salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night. ...
> <sup>**12**</sup> "Therefore rejoice, O heavens, and you who dwell in them! But woe to the earth and the sea; with great fury the devil has come down to you, knowing he has only a short time.” (Rev 12:7-10, 12)

The Bible says of sin and those who engage in it...

> <sup>**4**</sup> Everyone who practices sin practices lawlessness as well. Indeed, sin is lawlessness. <sup>**5**</sup> But you know that Christ appeared to take away sins, and in Him there is no sin. <sup>**6**</sup> No one who remains in Him keeps on sinning. No one who continues to sin has seen Him or known Him.
> <sup>**7**</sup> Little children, let no one deceive you: The one who practices righteousness is righteous, just as Christ is righteous.
> <sup>**8**</sup> The one who practices sin is of the devil, because the devil has been sinning from the very start. This is why the Son of God was revealed, to destroy the works of the devil. (1 John 3:4-7)

John 3:16 says...

> For God so loved the world that He gave His one and only Son, that everyone who believes in Him shall not perish but have eternal life.

So given the above, and in particular the notion that Christ made available an offer of salvation by grace through faith to mankind, was that same offer made to those angels and indeed even Lucifer himself during/or after the rebellion in heaven?

Comment: 'Salvation is of the Lord' it is written. Salvation is not 'available'. God saves whom he will. I don't understand the question. Some more detail and further clarity would help, I suggest.

Comment: Origen believed in the possibility. I believe this question has been asked before.

Comment: @Ken Graham...i searched for this question here before asking it but nothing came up

Comment: The 'everlasting fire' was **created for** the devil and his angels.  Therefore one would have to determine when the lake of fire was created in order to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

St. Alphonsus di Liguori considers the reprobation of Satan in his booklet *Treatiste on Prayer*. He concludes that before he fell, he was given sufficient grace by means of prayer to be numbered among the elect angels, but by refusing to start praying or persevere in it, the grace was not turned efficacious.

St. Alphonsus di Liguori concludes that anyone who prays regularly, daily, and frequently will surely receive efficacious grace and anyone who neglects to pray will receive only sufficient grace. This is reflected in Hebrews: "And without faith it is impossible to please God, for whoever would approach him must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who seek him." (Hebrews 11:6)

Comment: @ Amatsuki I wonder how grace could have been extended to Lucifer before the fall given that the Bible only speaks of salvation after the fall of man...and not at time of the fall of Lucifer which is described in Revelation?

Comment: @Adam God is fair and equitable, so He gives everyone sufficient grace and He gives everyone a means to turn sufficient grace into efficient grace (prayer). If He didn't do that, then it would ultimately be His fault Satan is condemned.

Answer (score 0):

We know that people were created as lesser beings than angels:

> What is man that You are mindful of him,
> And the son of man that You visit him?
> For You have made him **a little lower than** the angels,
> And You have crowned him with glory and honor.
> — Psalms 8:4–5 (NKJV)

Paul refers to this psalm and says:

> For He has not put the world to come, of which we speak, in subjection to angels.
> …
> You have put all things in subjection under his feet.”
> For in that He put all in subjection under him,
> He left nothing that is not put under him.
> But now we do **not yet** see all things put under him.
> — Hebrews 2:5,8

Mankind, which included the incarnate Jesus, is still lower than the angels and has not yet received "*all things*".

But, the promise still stands, as described in the book of Hebrews (these are selections, but one should read it all):

> Inasmuch then as the children have partaken of flesh and blood, He Himself likewise shared in the same, that through death He might destroy him who had the power of death, that is, the devil,
> and release those who through fear of death were all their lifetime subject to bondage.
> For indeed He **does not give aid to angels**, but He does give aid to the seed of Abraham.
> — Hebrews 2:14–16

> Therefore, since **a promise remains** of entering His rest, … .
> — Hebrews 4:1

> For you have need of endurance, so that after you have done the will of God, you may **receive the promise**
> — Hebrews 10:36

> These all died in faith, **not having received the promises**, but having seen them afar off were assured of them, embraced them and confessed that they were strangers and pilgrims on the earth.
> — Hebrews 11:13

> Therefore, since **we are receiving a kingdom** which cannot be shaken, let us have grace, by which we may serve God acceptably with reverence and godly fear.
> — Hebrews 12:28

God has promised salvation to mankind, not to the angels.
And when mankind have received that immortality, they will no longer be *lower* than the angels, but *higher*:

> Do you not know that the saints will judge the world? And if the world will be judged by you, are you unworthy to judge the smallest matters?
> Do you not know that **we shall judge angels**? How much more, things that pertain to this life?
> — 1 Corinthians 6:2–3

The ultimate purpose of mankind is to become God's family, with Jesus as the eldest son.

> And we know that all things work together for good to those who love God, to those who are the called according to His purpose.
> For whom He foreknew, He also predestined to be conformed to the image of His Son, that He might be the firstborn among many brethren.
> — Romans 8:28,29

> I will be a Father to you, And you shall be My sons and daughters, Says the LORD Almighty
> — 2 Corinthians 6:18

> He who overcomes shall inherit all things, and I will be his God and he shall be My son.
> — Revelation 21:7

Angels may have a form of immortality, but they will never be God's children, and that is what salvation is all about.

Comment: @ Ray Butterworth.... the passages you have quoted in Hebrews Ch 4 relate to the Seventh Day Sabbath given to the Jews and that it is still a requirement in Pauls time (and unto today actually). Pauls statements early in Ch 4 of Hebrews is summed up  here in vs 9 "There remains, then, a Sabbath rest for the people of God. 10For whoever enters God’s rest also rests from his own work, just as God did from His. 11Let us, therefore, make every effort to enter that rest, so that no one will fall by following the same pattern of disobedience."

Comment: ...Hebrews 2 is talking about the incarnate Jesus. It specifically states in vs 5 &9 that it is not speaking about Angels and that we do not yet see everything that is subject to Him {christ}

Comment: ...so my understanding is that because the angels in heaven rebelled before the fall of man, their salvation would have been dependant on an event that predated Adam and Eve. This may very well be why the Heavenly sanctuary was setup from which the earthly plan given to Moses was a copy. Perhaps it was a spiritual messianic death that would saved angels who rebelled should they have chosen to repent?

Comment: @ Ray Butterwprth.... also, Thank you for quoting 1cor 6 "we shall judge the angels" I had not thought about this before in reference to Lucifer and his fallen angels.